# Angular2 - json object display name but get id when clicked in a list

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of names which looks like this:

```
 this.items = [
            {name : "Joe", id : 1},
            {name : "Bob", id : 2},
            {name : "Jane", id : 3},
        ];
```

They are a json object. I want to display the name in the list. When a user clicks on the name I need to be able to get the id.

The html looks like this:

```
<ul (click)='handleClick($event.target.textContent)'>
  <li *ngFor="#item of items">
    {{ item.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This shows a list of names, but I am unsure how to get the id when a name is clicked?

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you handle the click on the `li` element?

Comment: This way there is only one event handler which takes advantage of event bubbling

Answer (score 0):

you click on parent ul, probably you need click on li

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#item of items" (click)='handleClick(item.id)'>
    {{ item.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

try applying the  . property accesor {{ item.id }}

Comment: But I don't want the ID to display, I don't want it visible go the user only the name should be visible to the user. I need the ID go send to my server after the user is clicked so this information is not important to the user

Comment: then {{item.name}}

Comment: Sorry yes this is what I have currently wrote my question wrong. But how to get the ID once it is clicked.

Comment: console.log(item.id)